# Routing for persistant drawer in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, drawer

I want to use this as a navigation for my page ,
but i cant find out how to Link in the  index properly,

I already tried to put l the items apart  but that didnt work
whit  ,,

and

```
        <List>
          {['Home' , 'About', 'Services', 'Contact'].map((text, index) => (
            
            
            
            <ListItem button  key={text} >
              <ListItemIcon>
   {index === 0 && <HomeOutlinedIcon /> }
   {index === 1 && <InfoOutlined/>}
   {index === 2 && <SettingsOutlinedIcon />}
   {index === 3 && <MailIcon/>}
              </ListItemIcon>
                
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
            
          ))}
          
        </List>
```

Can someone, Show me how to correctly  route my navigation in this list.

Comment: I'm not sure about the index bit, but why not structure your array something like `[{ text: 'Home', Component: HomeOutlinedIcon }, ...]` and map both the text and component and not worry about the index?

Answer (score 1):

Just create pages for `'Home' , 'About', 'Services', 'Contact'` and use the navigate function from [reach-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

You just have to declare your routes in the app.js with your `path="/app/home"` etc and the component you want to render to the DOM, then use navigate("/app/home") so you should change your array to an object with the good route on each item like this

```js
const fieldsNames = [
  { value: "Home", icon: <SvgIcon component={SearchIcon} />, path: "/app/home" },
]
```

and map on those item with an onClick.